# How do I get copilot to autocomplete in IntelliJ terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, github-copilot

I have a version of IJ that provides autocomplete in the terminal. My coworker is using the same version of IJ with the co-pilot plugin installed but it doesn't provide autocomplete in the terminal only in the code editor. I tried looking for a setting but I don't see any differences in our setup. Does anyone know how to turn on terminal shell completion for co-pilot in Intellij?